# Media Player in Qt

Tags: qt

I am posting this to know whether a media player can be developed with Qt5 without using gstreamer plugins as backend.Is there any other backend engine available in embedded linux platform to play media files other than gstreamer. I am using intel X86 32 bit architecture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What embedded platform are you using? Why is gstreamer not an option?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the Qt5 plugin sources (/qt5/qtmultimedia/src/plugins) and it seems like gstreamer is the only option for linux. Phonon has been dropped in Qt5.

If you want to use phonon you'll have to stick with Qt 4.8.

Comment: One of the issues with Qt5 and embedded is making sure the board has OpenGL support, so 4.8 might not be an awful idea.

Answer (score 1):

Qt5 on Linux only supports gstreamer by using the plugins in http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/trees/stable/src/plugins. Of course you can write your own plugin using ffmpeg or whatever you want. This is pretty simple, but entirely depends in the performance you need.

Phonon was available in Qt 4, but AFAIK Phonon is gstreamer based again. There is also a project to create a vlc-based Phonon, but I don't really know how it works (https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdesupport/phonon).

However, you don't specify your specific target, but if you want to achieve acceptable performance for graphics and/or video on embedded devices, you probably really need hardware acceleration. And Phonon will hardly help you with this. Also consider that Qt 4 is old: it misses years of development.

I'm also writing a Qt5 backend using OpenMAX and ffmpeg: http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.it/2013/04/hardware-accelerated-qtmultimedia.html. It might be an example if you need to write your own.

Also consider that the errors you reported (why reporting in an answert?) seem to suggest you built gstreamer wrong.